# How to pass json parameters in jmeter?

Tags: dynamic, jmeter, parameter-passing

In jmeter, I want to pass dynamic parameters. For simple json its easy to put ${value1} but if json structure is complex like array or with multiple values then what is the proper method to pass parameter dynamically. Please refer below json.
Below is json with parameter :

{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Eternal Flame",
      "age": 1000000,
      "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
      "powers": [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

=======
Now I have used below method to send parameter through csv config file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any other simple method to pass parameter through variables in Jmeter for complex json (5-6 level with array data) ?

Answer (score 0):

CSV DATA config is the best to parameterize your test data.

If you want to customize the way you want to pick values from CSV you can use [BeanShell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) /[JSR223 sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

here is [one article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users/) that shows how to pick random values from CSV data config.